# Passing datatable from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to copy datatable to another form.

Form1.cs

```
public DataTable Data1
{
    get { return dtDetailsAll; }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
Form1 m = new Form1();
dtSessionst = m.Data1.Copy();
```

However it doesn't copy the values. Can you help me on it ?

Comment: You're making a new (empty) instance of Form1 and getting the data from there, is there any data in there when you open it at first? because this wont work if not. If you need the data in form 2 just pass it as parameter to form2 :)

Comment: @EpicKip Could you please write as an answer?

Comment: do you open form2 from form1? and when you open it is the data already present in form1?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong instance of `Form1` in `Form2.cs`. using the key word `new` :

```
Form1 m = new Form1();
```

you create a new instance which is different from that one where the full `DataTable Data1` exists.

Solution: You need to pass the right instance to `Form2`.

1) create a second constructor in `Form2` which can take a `Form1` as parameter

2) save it in a class field:

```
private Form1 frm1;
public Form2(Form1 f1)
{
    frm1 = f1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

3) now you can use this variable to access `Data1`:

```
dtSessionst = frm1.Data1.Copy();
```

Comment: I did this however, empry form appears, control are not initializing. Both constructor should have InitializeComponent(); ?

Comment: I read your comment yesterday. It is important that you keep the original parameterless constructor and make a "second" one. Yes both constructors need the `InitializeComponent()` call, otherwise no controls will be on the form. You can call the original constructor from the second constructor like this: `public Form2(Form1 f1) : this(){...}` this way the `InitializeComponent` call will be made irrespective of which constructor you use.